# Mongoose.js: Save with a empty ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

How can I save with a empty ObjectId. I wanna create a item, thats not attach to any user yet. So the owner has to be a empty ObjectId.

How to do this?

Comment: You could have tried with null, without asking a question here...

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni While I agree that trying is the best way, I don't think it's bad to have a question here. Many questions here could have been solved by "just trying to do the right thing instead of asking".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you made the owner a required field then you must set a value, otherwise you may leave it null/undefined when saving.

Comment: tried it, and it works fine. Had no idea about that I could set it to null. Thank you :-)